# Xamarin forms Android / iOS status bar foreground / background color

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, statusbar

I am building a cross platform app using Xamarin forms on a mac using Visual code for mac.

I need to be able to change the status bar text and background colors on both the iOS and Android version of the APP.

I tried James Montemagno's solution from his video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKJRR8_DSSs

So every thing was good till we needed to use this code `window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility`
This code is deprecated and Visual Studio does not offert any hint to what I can use instead. I have tried to find but all I get is Android native related information [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577645/android-view-view-systemuivisibility-deprecated-what-is-the-replacement).

I really wish I would not have to use "native" code for some thing so basic in mobile App development. I understand that using the Shell class will allow me do use the minimal amount of "native" code possible, really wish to avoid coding any native code if possibly.

Context: I need to set the Android version of the app so that is has a white status bar and black text. Also I have 1 page with a black background image taking the full view, so on this page I need the status bar to be transparent and use a white foreground color.

So what does replace `window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = darkStatusBarTint ? flag : 0;` ??

The app is targeting Android API 30.

This is the code that is in the video

```
From main project stub
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    
    namespace MyApp.Helpers
    {
        public interface IEnvironment
        {
            void SetStatusBarColor(Color color, bool darkStatusBarTint);
        }
    }

From android stub
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using Android.OS;
    using EGrid18.Helpers;
    using Xamarin.Essentials;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Color = System.Drawing.Color;
    using DependencyAttribute = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyAttribute;
    
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyApp.Droid.Environment))]
    namespace MyApp.Droid
    {
        public class Environment: IEnvironment
        {
            
            public void SetStatusBarColor(Color color, bool darkStatusBarTint)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                    return;
                var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
                var window = activity.Window;
                window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                window.ClearFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
                window.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToPlatformColor());
    
                if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
                {
                    var flag = (Android.Views.StatusBarVisibility)Android.Views.SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
    #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Le type ou le membre est obsolète
                    //problen is here
                    window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = darkStatusBarTint ? flag : 0;
    #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Le type ou le membre est obsolète
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"all I get is Android native related information"* - Xamarin.Android c# code is 1:1 with corresponding native java/kotlin code. (all the same API calls; just different naming. Sometimes a property instead of get/set methods.) Have you tried to convert to c# the "native" code you found? If you are having trouble with that, **add to question** the link(s) you found, the relevant "native" code, and your best attempt at converting to c#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74115296/4308455
Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74115296/4308455

By the way, there is always some level of native API code involved in cross-platform development as there are differences between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As *systemUiVisibility* property is deprecated, you could use *WindowInsetsControllerCompat*. Refer to [jamesmontemagno's MyCoffeeApp](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mycoffeeapp?WT.mc_id=friends-0000-jamont) and try the following code:

```
WindowCompat.GetInsetsController(window, window.DecorView).AppearanceLightStatusBars = darkStatusBarTint;
```

That means if set *AppearanceLightStatusBars* to true, then changes the foreground color of the status bars to light so that the items on the bar can be read clearly.

For more information, you could see [WindowInsetsControllerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat)

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the status bar text and icons remain legible when you set the status bar color, then you can do the following:

```cs
public void SetSystemBarColor(Color color, bool lightStatusBarTheme)
{
    Window?.SetStatusBarColor(color);

    var statusBarFlags = lightStatusBarTheme ? (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars : 0;
    Window?.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance(statusBarFlags, (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars);
}
```

Then call it as follows in your Activity:

```cs
//black status bar
SetSystemBarColor(Color.Black, false);

//white status bar
SetSystemBarColor(Color.White, true);
```